# How Can I Get the Average Value in a CSV Grouped By Two Other Fields?

Tags: powershell, csv, command-line

I have a CSV file which looks like

```
TAG_ONE, 11, 10/27/2014,12:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_ONE, 12, 10/27/2014,1:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_ONE, 15, 10/27/2014,2:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_ONE, 25, 10/27/2014,3:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_ONE, 76, 10/28/2014,12:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_TWO, 78, 10/27/2014,9:00:00 PM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_TWO, 79, 10/27/2014,10:00:00 PM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_TWO, 78, 10/27/2014,11:00:00 PM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_TWO, 45, 10/28/2014,12:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
```

I am attempting to get a new CSV file which averages all the values in the second column by date (third column) and tag (first column).
So for each tag, for each date I get one row back with the average value.
Something like...

```
TAG_ONE, 15.75, 10/27/2014,12:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_ONE, 76,    10/28/2014,12:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_TWO, 78.33, 10/27/2014,12:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
TAG_TWO, 45,    10/28/2014,12:00:00 AM,11,Alm Disabled
```

I am completely new to powershell.  I can get the average of all values for a tag, but can't get them split up by date as well and after that I am clueless as to how to build a new csv file from that.

The end goal is to take lots of data points for lots of tags and turn it into one data point per day per tag.

Below is what I have so far.  I can group the items and display them back, but I can't seem to figure out how to average out all the values in a group once they are grouped.  I get an error that group.value cannot be found but if I just attempt to print $item.group.value they all print just fine.

```
$csv = import-csv -path \\psf\Home\Desktop\GitHub\iFix_Polling\Testing\HourlyTest.csv -header 'tag','value','date','time','unknown','alarm'

$collection = $csv | group-object -property tag,date

foreach( $item in $collection) {    
    $item | measure-object -property group.value -average
}
```

Comment: You would get less flack if you include what code you do have for the average calculation. Perhaps you almost have the solution already and you just need the community to help with the rest. Right now it appears as if you are looking for a from scratch solution which is not what SO is here for.

Comment: What do you do with the resulting CSV?. I suggest you import this data into a database and do the work in there.

Comment: Since you are new and I think this is a matter of 'I don't know what I don't know', and you not really knowing what to look for take these cmdlets: Group-Object, Measure-Object, Add-Member, ForEach-Object, Select-Object and Export-CSV. run `Get-Help Group-Object -full` and repeat for the others. Those are all what I needed to perform what you want. (aside from Import-CSV which I assume you know how to use)

Comment: I'll take a look at those cmdlets and see what I can come up with on my own and then bring it back here.

Comment: Perfect! If you can't figure it out come on back, post your code, and let us know what is going wrong. I know we can get it working for you. We like to see that you tried, and where things went wrong. We are all for helping you fix your code, we just don't like to do the work for you. Many of us get paid to do things like that.

Comment: I can manage to group objects by tag & date, or manage to get the average of all the values, but I cannot seem to get the average of all the values for a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give my two bits. I'd personally group things, then for each group take the first item, add a member that is the group's average, and just passthrough that item. Pipe that to a select to get the properties that you want, and pipe it all to Export-CSV:

```
$csv = import-csv -path \\psf\Home\Desktop\GitHub\iFix_Polling\Testing\HourlyTest.csv -header 'tag','value','date','time','unknown','alarm'
$collection = $csv | group-object -property tag,date
$collection | Foreach{
    $avg = $_.group|measure -Property Value -Average|select -expand average
    add-member -inputobject $_.group[0] -notepropertyname 'Average' -notepropertyvalue $avg -PassThru
}|Select Tag,Average,Date,SuperImportantNumber,AlarmStatus|Export-CSV $env:userprofile\desktop\Output.csv -notype
```

You already have a perfectly good object with most of the data that you want, not much reason to make even more objects that are virtual copies of what you already have.

That'll drop the output csv on your desktop. You can modify the path as desired, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Now that I have my bearings on this I can get to learning things more.  I was thrown into doing this with no prior knowledge of PowerShell scripts and an unreasonable deadline.  Just getting myself oriented at all was overwhelming without the luxury of just trying to learn.
I have modified what you have given me to do exactly what I need.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you were only interested in the tag,data and value this would wrap up in a simple `Select-Object` nicely.

```
$data = Import-Csv e:\temp\data.txt -Header "Tag","Value","Date","Time","SuperImportantNumber","AlarmStatus"
$data | Group-Object -Property tag,date | Select-Object @{Label ="Tag"; Expression ={($_.Name.split(","))[0]}},
        @{Label ="Average"; Expression ={ [math]::Round(($_.Group.Value | Measure-Object -Average).Average,2)}},
        @{Label ="Date"; Expression ={($_.Name.split(","))[1]}}
```

Else you could do something like this. It's unfortunately adds more complexity than needed but it still works.

```
$data = Import-Csv e:\temp\data.txt -Header "Tag","Value","Date","Time","SuperImportantNumber","AlarmStatus"
$data | Group-Object -Property tag,date | ForEach-Object{
    $singleObject = $_.Group | Select -First 1
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Tag = $singleObject.Tag
        Average = [math]::Round(($_.Group.Value | Measure-Object -Average).Average,2)
        Date = $singleObject.Date
        Time = $singleObject.Time
        SuperImportantNumber = $singleObject.SuperImportantNumber
        AlarmStatus = $singleObject.AlarmStatus
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`Group-Object` is the main feature in this code. Using that you can collect objects in a group. In our case we are using the `tag` and `date` to group information. First though we import the data as a csv. Your sample did not have headers so I provided them for you. You can remove the `-Header` if you have your own but just keep in mind that the rest of the code is dependent on what the header names are. For each group that is created we create a custom object that contains all the fields of the imported file. We use `$singleObject = $_.Group | Select -First 1` to get the values outside of tag,date and average. Personally i didn't see a reason to include the other information after the date but you have that in your output. The average is calculated from all the `Values` in the group. `Measure-Object` does the averaging for us and the `[math]` method `Round` gives us 2 decimal places. Finally export it all to csv.